# Oracle PL/SQL Table memory usage vs temporary tables

Tags: oracle, memory, data-structures, plsql

I am incrementally pulling records from a Web Service. I need to set the status of any records in our local table that were not returned by the Web Service to 'DELETED';

I had intended to store the complete list of record IDs in a PL/SQL table and then perform a single UPDATE statement based on that.

I now estimate the memory usage of the record set to be ~615MB. How does the memory footprint of a PL/SQL table compare to using a global temporary table instead? Would it use a different part of Oracle's memory, PGA vs SGA for instance?

Performance isn't a major concern because this nightly job already runs in Production in an acceptable amount of time. I don't believe adding the 'DELETED' status piece will increase the run duration to affect users.

Comment: "Performance isn't a major concern because this is a nightly job." - this is going to bite you in the future (when your nightly job hasn't finished when people start working in the morning).

Comment: I should probably qualify this by saying I know how long the job takes because it already runs in Production. The DELETED status bit is new, but I don't believe it will increase the run duration enough to impact users.

Comment: And what is the reason for accumulating those records instead of updating them as they come? What is the rate at which they arrive?

Comment: I'm going to set the status to 'DELETED' using a MINUS query. I can't do it incrementally as they come because I don't yet have the complete set of records that are active. Having any records incorrectly set as 'DELETED', even just for the duration of the job isn't acceptable in this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A global temporary table would not use memory in that way. It stores the values in a temporary segment to which only your session has access, and which is dropped when no longer needed.

Have you considered what happens if your session disconnects? In either method you lose the values you have accumulated. You might like to just use a regular table.

Comment: This is being run from a DBMS_SCHEDULER job. Is it likely to disconnect in that way?

Comment: I would always plan for recovery, either by re-polling the data source or by storing retrieved data, regardless. The database itself could crash or be shutdown.

Comment: With you. Fortunately the script is stateless. It doesn't matter if it's interrupted halfway, or indeed if some of the records fail, or the DELETED bit doesn't run, it will just pick up next time.